# Can we develop Tizen TV application by using native language?

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

Can we develop Tizen TV application by using native language ?
We have developed Samsung Tizen TV app by using HTML5, javascript and jquery.

We have picked a correct language to develop Tizen Application ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can :) Look for it NaCl on http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/nacl/getting-started.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use using NaCl (Tizen Native Client). However, there is an important notice [here](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/nacl/getting-started):

> **Important:**
> Due to NaCl deprecation by the Chromium project, Tizen TV
> will continue its support for NaCl only until 2021-year products.
> Meanwhile, Tizen TV will start focusing on high-performance,
> cross-browser WebAssembly from 2020-year products.

[Here is getting started page for Tizen WebAssembly](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/extension-libraries/webassembly/getting-started/downloading-and-installing.html)

Answer (score -1):

I think now they are supporting CSharp using dotnet framework.

For native, C/C++ maybe you get access to platform API as a partner, apply on samsung developer portal and keep us updated.

https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/TV